# Ignore mismatched tag in xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

Is there is any way to ignore mismatched tags in Python xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser?

Comment: No, there isn't. If there are mismatched tags then what you have is not well-formed. That means that it is not XML. The `XMLParser` class in lxml has a `recover` argument (http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html), but there is nothing like that in ElementTree.

Answer (score 6):

If there are mismatched tags, then the input that you are processing is not XML by definition (since it is not well-formed). There is no way to "ignore" mismatched tags with ElementTree.

---

The `XMLParser` class in the lxml library has a `recover` constructor argument (see http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html). When `recover=True`, lxml will try to fix ill-formed input. Example:

```
from lxml import etree

BADINPUT = """
<root> 
  <foo>ABC</bar> 
  <baz>DEF</baz> 
</root>"""

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
root = etree.fromstring(BADINPUT, parser)
print etree.tostring(root)
```

Output (the bad `</bar>` end tag has been changed to `</foo>`):

```
<root> 
  <foo>ABC</foo>
  <baz>DEF</baz> 
</root>
```